# Can Google Maps timeline distingish the height of the place I visited?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps timeline records the places I visited automatically. Interestingly, it seems to distinguish whether it was a 2nd floor or a 3rd floor that I visited.

Is it based on some machine learning algorithm that guesses which is the most likely place that I visit at that time, or on any mechanism that can measure the height of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps records the places you visit using different types of information, such as GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular network information. In addition, Google Maps can determine which floor you are on, using elevation information and GPS and Wi-Fi signals. Google Maps uses various methods, including machine learning, to improve location, but the exact algorithm that is used is not disclosed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).